# How to remove space occupied by a button by button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS. I want to know how to remove space occupied by a button instead of hiding the button.

[image: first image]

First I have 3 buttons. After clicking on button 2 I want to remove the space occupied by button 2 and change the position of button 3 position

[image: final image]

Comment: Simple hide the button by using this button.isHidden = YES.

Comment: button.isHidden = YES only hide the button but not remove the space occupied by the button

Comment: @sasikumar, do you ask android question?

Comment: you can remove space occupied by the by this [button removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Use a UIStackView. It does this automatically when you set the button to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you have explained in the image, you can write your button2 action method like

```
-(IBAction)btn2Action:(UIButton *)sender
{
    button2.hidden = TRUE;
//    Change y value (if you have all three buttons in vertical) of button 3 Frame Like:
    CGRect btn3Frame = button3.frame;
    btn3Frame.origin.y = button2.frame.origin.y;
    button3.frame = btn3Frame;


//    Change x value (if you have all three buttons in Horizontal) of button 3 Frame Like:
    CGRect button3Frame = button3.frame;
    button3Frame.origin.x = button2.frame.origin.x;
    button3.frame = button3Frame;
}
```